# grunt change location-specific urls in javascript

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm brand new to Grunt.  I'm wondering if there's a way, while grunt compiles all my .js into a single file, to change location-specific urls (like production and dev endpoints).

I've came across grunt when I began using [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate) to build my angular project.  I've noticed in the index.html, grunt inserts a specific .js file in the header using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.name') %>.js"></script>
```

But, when I followed that pattern in a .js file, say set a variable to `var url = '<%= grunt.config.get('pkg.url') %>'`, I was not awarded with a similar insertion (after I updated the package.json to house the `url` field.

Is there a way to do this insertion on javascript files, or am I trying to do the impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use something like [grunt-string-replace](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-string-replace).

From the docs:

> Replaces strings on files by using string or regex patterns. Attempts to be a String.prototype.replace adapter task for your grunt project.